# Underdoped Cuprates

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, superconductivity

What does underdoped cuprates mean?

I guess cuprate is underdoped when hole concentration is less then optimal doping. Am I Right?. or it is something difference?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right.

You have optimally doped cuprates, which are samples with the highest possible transition or critical temperature $T_c$ for this one compound. Reducing the $T_c$ with increased doping gives you "overdoped" samples, reducing the $T_c$ with lowering the doping gives you "underdoped" samples.